# Как подменить или скрыть свои данные при регистрации?

Tags: google-account

Какие данные кроме MAC-адреса сетевой, IP, браузера и т.д Google может собрать при регистрации нового аккаунта?

Интересует к примеру если он может узнать MAC-адрес сетевой карты, может быть он может еще видеть id железа?

Comment: А откуда информация, что он получает mac-адрес. браузеры обычно не дают такой информации скриптам и следовательно собрать ее нельзя. я еще поверю что какой нибудь google chrome лично для гугла это соберет, но что бы IE например или опера ...

Comment: незнаю кто и что, но у гугла больше информации о вас чем Вы думаете, точнее о вашей системе. как он получает информацию не знаю, но мак-адрес у него есть, почитайте о блокировках AdWords-аккааунтов, многие советуют покупать дедик так как у него новый мак-адрес, соответственно не будет блокировки, т.е. у гугла не будет оснований полагать что много аккаунтов принадлнжат одному человеку

Comment: хотя не понимаю почему советуют новый дедик, когда мак сетевой можно изменить. получается гугл идентификует не только по маку но и по другому не понятно какому железу

Comment: @Mike, можно ваши контакты? аська, скайп, контакт, телеграм, в общем любой)